# How to wrap a fortran subroutine in c++

Tags: c++, fortran, fortran90

I have a very simple subroutine "myfun" in fortran 90 code

```
! test.f
SUBROUTINE  myfun(a, b, ans)
    IMPLICIT  NONE
    REAL, INTENT(IN)  :: a, b
    REAL, INTENT(OUT) :: ans
    ans = .5*(a + b)
END SUBROUTINE  myfun
```

How do I wrap it in c++? I am very new to fortran and have no clue. I can compile it with

```
gfortran -c -ffree-form test.f
```

Then, how do I call it within a c++ code? I know I have to use the external "C" command, but not sure how.

Comment: if your question is only about this routine, why not just rewrite it in C++ ?

Comment: Come on... There's a whole tag about that on SO! Do some research, show us what you tried, and we will help you!

Comment: The subroutine I will actually use is much more complicated. The example above is just a simplified example. 

Alex - Can you give me the link to the that tag?

Comment: He probably means [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding].

Comment: The name of that tag is little unfortunate, because that intrinsic module is not the most important thing in C interoperability. In this case one can easily just assume that float==real and don't use it at all. That's why the new TS is not named "Further features of iso-c-binding" but "Further Interoperability of Fortran with C".